# Building a Cache Key quickly

Tags: c#, .net, performance, hash, .net-4.5

I am using a custom cache implementation in a Web Api 2 application.  This cache stores hundreds of thousands of items and can be read from up to 10,000 times in a single API request.

On profiling, I have found that the actual building of each items' cache key is significantly affecting overall performance.

**Result from .NET profiling:**

[image: Sampling Profiler]

**Cache key details:**

I am building a the items' key by hashing a string.  E.g:

```
MySystem.MyProject.MyNamespace.MyClass.SomeMethod(44,6948)
```

This gets hashed into something like this, which is then used in the caching framework as the key (this is not longer used - refer to EDIT 3):

```
1bbbfeae-b143-77f2-8381-5ee11f5b9c0c
```

Obviously I need to ensure uniqueness on each key, but I can't seem to find a way to improve the performance here without introducing possible duplication.

**The key builder:**

```
public class CacheKeyBuilder
{
    private MethodInterceptionArgs methodArguments;

    public CacheKeyBuilder(MethodInterceptionArgs input)
    {
        methodArguments = input;
    }

    // No longer used - refer to EDIT 3
    public UInt64 GetHashedKey()
    {
        return Hash(GetFriendlyKey());
    }

    public string GetFriendlyKey()
    {
        if (methodArguments.Arguments.OfType<IList>().Any())
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Cannot create a keys from IList types");
        }

        var type = methodArguments.Binding.GetType();

        var key = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}{3}{4}",
            type.Namespace,
            type.DeclaringType.Name,
            methodArguments.Method.Name,
            type.UnderlyingSystemType.GenericTypeArguments.Select(x => x.Name).ToList().JoinItems("<", ">", ","),
            methodArguments.Arguments.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList().JoinItems("(", ")", ",")
        );

        return key;
    }

    // No longer used - refer to EDIT 3
    private UInt64 Hash(string key)
    {
        UInt64 hashedValue = 3074457345618258791ul;

        for (int i = 0; i < key.Length; i++)
        {
            hashedValue += key[i];
            hashedValue *= 3074457345618258799ul;
        }

        return hashedValue;
    }
}
```

**Considerations:**

- The key needs namespace, full type name, generics and all the property values to ensure uniqueness.
- `String.Format()` essentially implements a `StringBuilder`, so this should be the most efficient way of building strings.
- I got the hashing from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545619/a-fast-hash-function-for-string-in-c-sharp) (Knuth hash?), which is faster than my own previous implementations.

Can anyone spot any evident performance improvements that can be made?

**EDIT:**

Another consideration, based on David and Patryk's comments, is that I cannot hard code the "type" string.  The performance improvements need to be backwards compatible. I have to work with reflection.

**EDIT 2:**

Sorry, the hash methods are meant to return `UInt64`.  Code fixed.

**EDIT 3:**

Storing the hashed key vs the friendly key has made no difference in performance.  Thus, I am moving to the only using `GetFriendly()`.  Thanks usr.

Comment: Your `Hash` function returns a string.  If you're going to use a string as they key, then just use the original unhashed string: `MySystem.MyProject.MyNamespace.MyClass.SomeMethod(44,6948)`.  That said, I think your bottleneck is probably in `GetFriendlyKey()`.  I can't see your profiling screenshot.  Would hard-coded strings with parameters appended help any?

Comment: Reflection probably does not help here either...

Comment: Oh, and 10,000 lookups in one API call tells me you need some kind of context storage to minimize that.  Caching should mostly be _between_ calls.

Comment: @DavidCrowell: What do you mean "Caching should mostly be between calls."?  Perhaps I wasn't clear, but this is application-level caching, not web/http caching.

Comment: If you're recalling a cached value 10,000 times in one API call, you'd be better off storing that value in a variable for the duration of the call. `HttpContext.Current` comes to mind.  If you need it in a different call (different or same client), then, yes, retrieving from cache is the answer.  Either way, your caching mechanism is too slow - probably due to reflection.

Comment: @DavidCrowell:  I wasn't clear then - apologies.  I am not calling the same item 10,000 items.  It is that there could be 10,000 different items retrieved.

Comment: Edited post - Unfortunately I cannot use the "hard coded" string idea.  I have to work with reflection.

Comment: Why are you hashing the key that you generate?

Comment: Why does the result of Hash not match the format you gave as an example (a Guid)?

Comment: Does the hash key have to be a string?

Comment: @usr: I fixed the code.  `GetHash()` returning `UInt64`.

Comment: My other questions remain open. Does the hash have to be a UInt64, for example?

Comment: I can't understand how it's supposed to work. The method invocation signature is rebuilt as string, hashed, and used as key ... but what's the value ?

Comment: @usr: No, it doesn't need to be UInt64.  In fact, I have just tried without the hashing, and the performance is the same (even as a string).  My guess is that it is rehashed anyway. Post edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your using PostSharp.  [Their own example](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/SOLID-Caching) for caching generates the method name as a string *at compile time*.

It seems you could get the fully-qualified type name at the same time.  This would allow the expensive reflection only to occur at compile time.

```
public override void CompileTimeInitialize(MethodBase method, AspectInfo aspectInfo)
{
    _methodName = method.Name;
    _typeName = method.Binding.GetType().Namespace...  ..Name; // etc
}
```

I would also try the `StringBuilder.Append()` vs `string.Format()` and see if there's a peformance difference.

Comment: Fantastic.  This makes a significant difference.