# Convert a String to unique Long

Tags: c#, string, long-integer

I have a string made up of 2 parts (see code)

I want to know the UnknownDeterministicFunction which returns a Long, which can deterministically produce the same long for a given string.

```
private void MyProgram()
{
    string resultStr = "XXX"+"12345678";
    //1st part is a string of characters (the "XXX")
    //2nd part is a string of numbers (the "12345678")

    long resultLng = UnknownDeterministicFunction(myString);
}

private long UnknownDeterministicFunction(string inputStr)
{
    // ???
}
```

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: why the negative vote?

Comment: This seems kinda vague.  I mean if you don't want to be able to turn the long back into the string then any valid hash code algorithm would do what you want.

Comment: Ok makes sense - i may just use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545619/a-fast-hash-function-for-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: not even that - i will just use myString.GetHashCode()

Answer (score 3):

First of all

- there are **8 ** (2 ** 30)** different *string*s (which up to **2 GB** long)
- there are **2 ** 64** differrent *long* (which are **64-bit** integers)

So you can't guarantee `long` be *unique* (good old *Pigeonhole principle*). If you are ready for possible, though improbable *collisions* (i.e. different `string`s can well return the same `long`) you may want to implement *hash functions*, e.g.

[hash function for string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666509/hash-function-for-string)

or

[Good Hash Function for Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624192/good-hash-function-for-strings)

usually, hash function returns `Int32`; in that case just combine *two* `int` into one `long`

```
int hash1 = GetHashOneAlgorithm(myString); 
int hash2 = GetHashAnotherAlgorithm(myString); 

long result = ((long) hash1 << 32) | hash2;
```

Answer (score -1):

OK the answer is simple.

```
private long UnknownDeterministicFunction(string inputStr)
{
    //not taking care of null...
    return (long)inputStr.GetHashCode()
}
```

Comment: Two problems: first: if `inputStr == null` you'll have exception thrown; second: *hash* is good choice, but it doesn't *unique*. Sorry, the answer is not *that simple*.

Comment: Counter example: *different* strings `"9331582"` and `"942"` returns the *same* hash `-1864841629` (*C# 6.0 .Net 4.6*); so your solution didn't produce *unique* `long`