How do I convert this Knuth hash code in C# to the SQL equivalent?
Can anyone help me to convert the C# code below (Knuth hash) to the SQL equivalent?
/// <summary>
/// https://stackoverflow.com/a/9545731
/// </summary>
static string CalculateHash(string read)
{
    UInt64 hashedValue = 3074457345618258791ul;
    for (int i = 0; i < read.Length; i++)
    {
        hashedValue += read[i];
        hashedValue *= 3074457345618258799ul;
    }
    return hashedValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016.
Also, as pointed out here, in SQL you can use the NUMERIC(20) datatype for 64-bit unsigned integer values.
Thank you.

numeric and integer data types aren't the same. Hashing (normally) relies on the byte values of a value, and the byte values for numeric and an int64 are quite different.

You can't do this in SQL without a lot of work, because there's no way to a) use unsigned 64-bit integers, and b) deal with overflows. BIGINT is signed 64-bit integer, but without being able to deal with overflows you'd have to write a lot of 64-bit integer math synthesized from 32-bit operations using BIGINTs. It's a fun problem, but way too complex. Why do you need this?

Agree, sounds like an X & Y problem. But if you really need it, why not create some CLR class and you can almost certainly copy paste most of the implementation from the code above

I've prepared two potential SQL functions - one that performs calculations using NUMERIC(38,0) and one that performs calculation using BIGINT.
The BIGINT version required performing bit-slice arithmetic to keep the multiplication calculations within the limits of the underlying Int64 range of values. Even though the implementation is more complicated, it still might out-perform the NUMERIC(38,0) version because the BIGINT add, multiply, various bitwise operations used are natively supported by the processor. NUMERIC(38,0) is an emulated data type and the algorithm uses divide and remainder operations in the absence of bitwise masking and shift operations. I did not perform a performance test.
Both functions yield the same results and also match the results from the reference C# implementation for several test strings, including strings containing 16-bit characters and surrogate pairs for UNICODE characters above U+FFFF.
Here is the NUMERIC(38,0) version:
CREATE FUNCTION KnuthHashUnicode1(@String NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Adaptation of C# hash algorithm posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9545731, modified
    -- to return a string result as requested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78357462
    -- WARNING: This hash is **not** crypographically secure.

    -- NOTE: This algorithm depends on the fact that the @Multiplier value is such
    -- that @Multiplier * @TwoPower64 does not exceed the NUMERIC(38,0) capacity.
  
    -- Key values
    DECLARE @Seed       NUMERIC(38,0) =  3074457345618258791
    DECLARE @Multiplier NUMERIC(38,0) =  3074457345618258799
    DECLARE @TwoPower64 NUMERIC(38,0) = 18446744073709551616 -- 2^64
    
    -- Initialize
    DECLARE @Hash NUMERIC(38,0) = @Seed
    
    -- Get the true length of string, including possible trailing spaces
    DECLARE @Len INT = DATALENGTH(@String) / 2
    
    DECLARE @Pos INT = 0
    WHILE @Pos < @Len
    BEGIN
        SET @Pos += 1
        DECLARE @Value BIGINT = UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@String, @Pos, 1))
        
        SET @Hash = (@Hash + @Value) % @TwoPower64
        SET @Hash = (@Hash * @Multiplier) % @TwoPower64
    END
    
    -- Format and return as string
    RETURN CAST(@Hash AS VARCHAR(20))
END

Here is the BIGINT version:
CREATE FUNCTION KnuthHashUnicode2(@String NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Adaptation of C# hash algorithm posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9545731, modified
    -- to return a string result as requested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78357462
    -- WARNING: This hash is **not** crypographically secure.

    -- Key values are conveniently < 2^63, so they fit in a signed BIGINT.
    DECLARE @Seed BIGINT = 3074457345618258791
    DECLARE @Mult BIGINT = 3074457345618258799
    
    -- We will be doing arithmatic in three slices: 2 x 24-bit and 1 x 16-bit
    DECLARE @Mask24 BIGINT = 0xFFFFFF -- 24 bits (Lo and Md parts)
    DECLARE @Mask16 BIGINT = 0xFFFF   -- 16 bits (Hi part)
    
    DECLARE @SeedLo BIGINT = @Seed & @Mask24
    DECLARE @SeedMd BIGINT = (@Seed >> 24) & @Mask24
    DECLARE @SeedHi BIGINT = @Seed >> 48
    
    DECLARE @MultLo BIGINT = @Mult & @Mask24
    DECLARE @MultMd BIGINT = (@Mult >> 24) & @Mask24
    DECLARE @MultHi BIGINT = @Mult >> 48
    
    -- Initialize
    DECLARE @HashHi BIGINT = @SeedHi
    DECLARE @HashMd BIGINT = @SeedMd
    DECLARE @HashLo BIGINT = @SeedLo
    
    -- Get the true length of string, including possible trailing spaces
    DECLARE @Len INT = DATALENGTH(@String) / 2
    
    DECLARE @Pos INT = 0
    WHILE @Pos < @Len
    BEGIN
        SET @Pos += 1
        DECLARE @Value BIGINT = UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@String, @Pos, 1))
        
        -- Add with carry
        DECLARE @SumLo BIGINT = @HashLo + @Value
        DECLARE @SumMd BIGINT = @HashMd + (@SumLo >> 24)
        DECLARE @SumHi BIGINT = @HashHi + (@SumMd >> 24)
        SET @HashLo = @SumLo & @Mask24
        SET @HashMd = @SumMd & @Mask24
        SET @HashHi = @SumHi & @Mask16
        
        -- Cross-multiply with carry
        -- (No need to calculate product components > 64 bits)
        DECLARE @ProdLo BIGINT = (@HashLo * @MultLo)
        DECLARE @ProdMd BIGINT = (@HashMd * @MultLo)
                               + (@HashLo * @MultMd)
                               + (@ProdLo >> 24)
        DECLARE @ProdHi BIGINT = (@HashHi * @MultLo)
                               + (@HashMd * @MultMd)
                               + (@HashLo * @MultHi)
                               + (@ProdMd >> 24)
        SET @HashLo = @ProdLo & @Mask24
        SET @HashMd = @ProdMd & @Mask24
        SET @HashHi = @ProdHi & @Mask16
    END
    
    -- Combine slices
    DECLARE @Result BIGINT = (@HashHi << 48) | (@HashMd << 24) | (@HashLo)

    -- Convert to numeric and adjust for negative
    DECLARE @ResultNum NUMERIC(20,0) = CAST(@Result AS NUMERIC(20,0)) 
    IF @ResultNum < 0 SET @ResultNum += 18446744073709551616 -- 2^64

    -- Format and return as string
    RETURN CAST(@ResultNum AS VARCHAR(20))
END

Sample results (including 16-bit and surrogate UNICODE characters):



String
Result1
Result2




(empty string)
3074457345618258791
3074457345618258791


(single space)
16397105843297422473
16397105843297422473


Hello World
5485109609273439365
5485109609273439365


Hello World (w/trailing space)
10073154357816199819
10073154357816199819


αβγδ абвг 你好世界 ∫∬∭∮ 
5168594500780613104
5168594500780613104


The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
5118964073116902044
5118964073116902044



See this db<>fiddle for a demo. For comparison with the C# results, see this .NET fiddle.
